# how to get whole html inside the node in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

could you please tell me how to get whole html inside the tag ?

here is my code

http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LVQ/1

**expected output**

```
<li>
    <strong>dddd</strong>
    <div>
        <div col="1">d<p>ddd</p></div>

    </div>
</li>
<li>
<strong>ccc</strong>
<div>
    <div col="1">iii<p>ddd</p></div>

</div>
</li>
```

**Input**

```
<a>
    <cd>
           <title>dddd</title>

        <body>
            <div col="1">d<p>ddd</p></div>
        </body>
    </cd>
     <cd>
       <title>ccc</title>
        <body>
            <div col="1">iii<p>ddd</p></div>
        </body>
    </cd>
</a>
```

**my output**

```
 <li><strong>dddd</strong><div>
         dddd

      </div>
   </li>
   <li><strong>ccc</strong><div>
         iiiddd

      </div>
   </li>
```

**update**

```
<li><strong>dddd</strong><div>

    <div col="1">d
        <p>ddd</p>
    </div>

</div>
</li>
<li><strong>ccc</strong><div>

    <div col="1">iii
        <p>ddd</p>


        <img  src="abc.png"/>

    </div>

</div>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the XSLT in it, please? xsltransform.net is great, but it does have a habit of becoming unavailable often, which would limit this question's use. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `<xsl:value-of select="body"/>` to `<xsl:copy-of select="body/node()"/>`. In the future make sure you show your XSLT in the question. And please don't use a tag like xslt-grouping if the question does not include any grouping problem.

Comment: I have one more querry ..Thanks for answer .working fine

Comment: if in the `body` body any div contain `data-type` =="image" ..can We add `img` tag ?

Comment: please see update and update http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LVQ/2 ..in second item I have `data-type="image"` i need to add img tag ..can i ?

Comment: any idea ? can I achieve this ?

Comment: This is really a second question you should ask separately, if you use `<xsl:apply-templates select="body/node()"/>` instead of the copy-of suggested above, you can then add a template `<xsl:template match="div[@data-type = 'image']"><img src="@src"/></xsl:template>` and of course then you also need the identity transformation template you had earlier.